# Javascript Standard Object - How To Return Two Elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, associative-array

If I have the Standard Object

```
 var data = [];

 data["Name"] = ["Janet", "James", "Jean", "Joe", "John"];
 data["Number"] = [25, 22, 37, 19, 40];
```

Say I want the minimum number value '19'

How can I return and display the Name associated with the minimum number value?  What about the Name associated with the maximum value?

Basically, how can I return two elements at once and how can I find out if they are associated with each other?

I've tried indexOf() but methods don't work properly on Standard Objects.
I'm fairly new to Javascript.

EDITED:  forgot the square brackets on the array...

Comment: lot's of bugs in your code

Comment: I think you are missing some `[...]` around your data.

Comment: `var data = {};

 data["Name"] = ["Janet", "James", "Jean", "Joe", "John"];
 data["Number"] = [25, 22, 37, 19, 40];`

Comment: Whoops, just added the square brackets.  Sorry I totally forgot

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`Math.min.apply`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Using_Math.max()) to get `smallest` value from `array` and `Array#indexOf` to get index of the `smallest` number

```js
var data = {}; //Initialize it as object

data["Name"] = ["Janet", "James", "Jean", "Joe", "John"];
data["Number"] = [25, 22, 37, 19, 40];

var min = Math.min.apply(null, data["Number"]);
console.log(min);
console.log(data["Name"][data["Number"].indexOf(min)]);
//-----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^To get the index of smallest number
```

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek – `Associative array` but less `readable` and _confusing_

Comment: It works with [] because array is an object like any other in JS that can dynamically have properties added to it. Nothing oddly about it, it will work with any reference object in JS.

Comment: I'm getting Uncaught Type error on data.Number.indexOf (it says it's not a function)... anybody else?

Comment: @5120bee – Did you click on __Run code snippet__ to test ?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution using ES6 [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function:

```
// search for MAX number
var idx = data["Number"].indexOf(Math.max.apply(null, data["Number"])),
    nameWithMax = data["Name"].find((v, i) => i === idx);
console.log(nameWithMax);  // "John"
```